# NIC connection between computers: Lost connection

Tags: networking

What might cause Ethernet connection randomly drop off between two computers.I'm using one computer(win7) as a server,second as a "slave1"(win10) and third as a "slave2"(win10).
All computers have Gigabit Ethernet cards.
I'm using cross wired Ethernet cables between computers. Windows log shows that the link has been disconnected randomly.

Comment: Dud cable, pretty much guaranteed.

Comment: A bad cable is a primary contender, but there are other possibilities including bad firmware or hardware (especially realtec chipsets), or possibly a DHCP/IP addressing issue.